# Left semi-Fredholm property of operator implied because closed linear subspaces have closed images.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$ and let $A : H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator, which is not finite rank.

Suppose that for every closed linear subspace $M$ of $H$ the image $A(M)$ is closed. Does it follow that $A$ is left semi-Fredholm?

The reverse implication is true and I think well-known.